# js modules loaded by systemjs not showing up in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, systemjs

I recently implemented SystemJs to load js modules for my site. The js files loaded by SystemJS were displaying in chrome dev tools when I loaded each js file individually like this:

```
SystemJS.import('Globals.js'))
```

However, I modified my SystemJs loading routine to be more dynamic:

```
  var modules = 
  [
    'MyModule1',
    'MyModule2',        
    'MyModule3'
  ];  

Promise.all(modules.map(x => System.import(x + '.js')))
```

When I use this more dynamic approach, the js files no longer display in my chrome dev tools. I tried "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" and also deleted all files from my Windows temp folder. Any idea what the issue might be or how to fix?

Chrome Dev Tools shows other js libs loaded outside of the dynamic SystemJs load routine.  These files are displayed in the Sources nav tree as expected. The Network view in Chrome Dev Tools shows all scripts loaded outside of the dynamic SystemJs load routine.  However, this view also does not show a reference to the js scripts loaded by the dynamic SystemJs load routine.

Comment: any difference between `SystemJS.import` and `System.import`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with System.import but SystemJS.import is specific to the SystemJS js lib

Comment: Workaround: use `debugger` statement to make devtools show the code in a tab (it might not appear in file tree pane but at least you'll be able to debug it properly).